# How to Autowire a bean conditionally based on the type value from REST API request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am a novice in the process of learning Spring and have encountered a question regarding how to use autowiring to inject a bean based on the value from the request type.

For ex,

```
public interface shape {

   Handler draw(ShapeRequest request);
}
```

```
@Component 
public class Circle {
   ...
}
```

```
@Component
public class Rectangle {
    ...
}
```

I have a class where I need to invoke either the circle or rectangle based on the value received in the ShapeRequest.shape. Could someone please provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach is to create both Components and to Inject them both, but you can use the Factory Pattern to return the one you wish to use.

```
@Component 
public class Circle implements Shape{
   ...
}
@Component
public class Rectangle implements Shape{

    ...
}
```

//pseudo code below

```
@Component
public class ShapeFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    @Autowired
    private Circle circle;

    public Shape getShapeComponent(ShapeEnum requestShape) {

      //circle 
      if(requestShape.equals(ShapeEnum.CIRCLE){
         return circle;
      }

     ..... rest

}
```

---

```
   @Component
   public class MyMainClass{

      @Autowired
      private ShapeFactory shapeFactory;


      public void someMethod(){

         ShapeEnum shapeEnum = someRequestThatReturnsShape();

         shapeFactory.getShapeComponent(shapeEnum);

      }
   }
```